# How to get .ts file in developer tool while using webpack as module bundler in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I am using webpack as module bundles for developing angular2 application.It creates bundle.js file.I am unable to get .ts file in developer tool so that I can debug it.Any solution?

```
          //var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            'app': "./App/main.ts",
            'employee': "./App/EmployeeModule/employee.module",
            'supplier': "./App/SupplierModule/supplier.module",
            'product': "./App/ProductModule/product.module"
        },
        output: {
            path: __dirname + "/dist",
            filename: "[name].js",
            chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js",
            publicPath: "/dist/",
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"]
        },
        module: {
            rules:
                [
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ["ts-loader", "angular2-template-loader", "angular2-router-loader"]
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']             },

                {
                    test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i, loader: "file-loader"
                },
                { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
            ],
    },

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Source Maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)**.

1. Enable source maps generation for TypeScript in your `tsconfig.json` :

   ```
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "sourceMap": true
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add sourcemaps link in generated JavaScript files by adding this in `webpack.config.js`:

```js
    module.exports = {
      devtool: 'source-map'
    };
```

3. Enable Source Maps in your dev tools, if not enabled by default. For instance in Chrome, go in dev tools preferences: *Sources > Enable JavaScript source maps*.